# Why does MonthCalendar look different in 3rd party app?

Tags: c#, monthcalendar

I'm currently working on a plug-in dll for a 3rd party application.  Part of my dll includes a pop-up window with a `System.Windows.Forms.MonthCalendar` in it.  Now when I work on it in Visual Studio and when I open the pop-up with a test application I wrote it looks one way, but when the 3rd party app opens it, it looks different.  On top of looking different they also have different behaviors.  Does anyone have any idea why?  One thing that I thought might be an issue is that my dll is built with .Net 3.5 and the 3rd party app is .Net 2.0 (I think).  But when I built my test application as .Net 2.0 it still worked the same way.

Here's what I'm expecting:

[image]

And here's what I'm getting:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 3rd-party application is not enabling visual styles, and is therefore falling back on the classic Windows UI theme.  Note that the button and combo boxes don't look the same either.  You would have to enable visual styles in the 3rd-party application to apply the current Windows theme to it.

(As an exercise, try switching your Windows preferences to use the classic theme and then look at the working test application -- it should look identical to the 3rd-party one.)

Comment: So is there a way to force my pop-up to use the classic Windows UI theme when called from the 3rd party app?

Comment: Possibly, but I would not force this.  Your control should be designed so that it works properly given any particular UI theme.  You seem to have designed it to work well only with the Vista/7 theme.  Consider using an auto-sizing table layout instead of an X,Y layout, and test using as many themes as you can get your hands on (within reason).

Comment: Yep, removing `Application.EnableVisualStyles()` from my test app does produce the same result as the 3rd party app.  Now to see if I can turn it on for the 3rd party app.

Comment: You can try.  But to reiterate my point: if a control depends on a particular UI theme to be enabled then **that control is broken.**

Comment: I honestly don't care about the "look" of the control, but I do care about the functionality that does seem to change with the theme.  And I would like to not display dates outside the Min/Max Date range.

Comment: Perhaps you could nail down the behavior you want by subclassing MonthCalendar?